# JSON Schema not working as expected, this seems to be common issue when the property is boolean type

Tags: jsonschema, ajv

The following JSON Schema seems to be failing and I'm not sure why this is happening. I tried adding `not` `required` instead of `else`, but it had no effect. I've tried several things, but nothing seems to work. I want to make only one field strictly available and else based on some other boolean.

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "title": "Update app config Support & Ticketing",
      "type": "object",
        "properties": {
    "servicenowEnabled": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "servicenowClientId": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "servicenowClientSecret": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "servicenowBaseUrl": {
      "type": "string",
        "format": "regex",
          "pattern": ".*service-now.com$"
    },
    "servicenowKnowledgeBaseEnabled": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "servicenowKnowledgeBaseSelected": {
      "type": "object",
        "properties": {
        "showAll": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "selectedList": {
          "type": "array",
            "items": {
            "type": "object"
          },
          "properties": {
            "id": {
              "type": "string",
                "minLength": 1
            },
            "name": {
              "type": "string",
                "minLength": 1
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "showAll"
      ],
        "if": {
        "properties": {
          "showAll": {
            "const": true
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "selectedList": {
            "const": []
          }
        }
      },
      "else": {
        "properties": {
          "selectedList": {
            "minItems": 1
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "servicenowKnowledgeBaseName": {
      "type": "string",
        "minLength": 1
    },
    "servicenowKnowledgeBaseUrl": {
      "type": "string",
        "format": "uri"
    },
    "servicenowTicketsEnabled": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "servicenowTicketsName": {
      "type": "string",
        "minLength": 1
    },
    "servicenowTicketsUrl": {
      "type": "string",
        "format": "uri"
    },
    "servicenowCreateTicketsEnabled": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "servicenowNotificationEnabled": {
      "type": "boolean"
    }
  },
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "servicenowEnabled": {
            "const": true
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "required": [
          "servicenowEnabled",
          "servicenowBaseUrl"
        ]
      },
      "else": {
        "required": [
          "servicenowEnabled"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "servicenowKnowledgeBaseEnabled": {
            "const": true
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "required": [
          "servicenowKnowledgeBaseUrl",
          "servicenowKnowledgeBaseName",
          "servicenowKnowledgeBaseSelected"
        ]
      },
      "else": true
    }
  ],
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```

fails for the test case of

```json
{
  "servicenowEnabled": false,
  "servicenowBaseUrl": "http: //base-url.service-now.com",
  "servicenowClientId": "clientID",
  "servicenowClientSecret": "clientSecret"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had an error in the schema on line 34, `properties` was not defined correctly.

I fixed up the `if, then` statements for you. Now, the example you provided is passing.

- `servicenowEnabled` must be `required` in the `if` part of the conditional schema.
- if the value is `true`, `servicenowBaseUrl` is `required`

---

the same is true for the second `allOf` conditional statement

- `servicenowKnowledgeBaseEnabled` must be `required` for it to validate correctly.

> Note
> The “required” keyword is necessary in the `if` schemas or all properties would apply if no properties were defined or `required` at the root schema where the `if, then` conditions are present

I also added a few more constraints on `selectedList` `required` properties and the requirement of `selectedList` itself when the `showAll: false` condition is met.

Please check and let me know if that works for you.

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "Update app config Support & Ticketing",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "servicenowEnabled": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "servicenowClientId": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "servicenowClientSecret": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "servicenowBaseUrl": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "regex",
      "pattern": ".*service-now.com$"
    },
    "servicenowKnowledgeBaseEnabled": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "servicenowKnowledgeBaseSelected": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "showAll": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "selectedList": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": ["id", "name"],
            "properties": {
              "id": {
                "type": "string",
                "minLength": 1
              },
              "name": {
                "type": "string",
                "minLength": 1
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "required": ["showAll"],
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "showAll": {
            "const": false
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "required": ["selectedList"],
        "properties": {
          "selectedList": {
            "minItems": 1
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "servicenowKnowledgeBaseName": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "servicenowKnowledgeBaseUrl": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "uri"
    },
    "servicenowTicketsEnabled": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "servicenowTicketsName": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "servicenowTicketsUrl": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "uri"
    },
    "servicenowCreateTicketsEnabled": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "servicenowNotificationEnabled": {
      "type": "boolean"
    }
  },
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "required": ["servicenowEnabled"],
        "properties": {
          "servicenowEnabled": {
            "const": true
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "required": ["servicenowBaseUrl"]
      }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "required": ["servicenowKnowledgeBaseEnabled"],
        "properties": {
          "servicenowKnowledgeBaseEnabled": {
            "const": true
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "required": [
          "servicenowKnowledgeBaseUrl",
          "servicenowKnowledgeBaseName",
          "servicenowKnowledgeBaseSelected"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

Comment: Thanks jeremy , this seems to be passing the cases .